# Drag&Drop application Julia Gtk

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, gtk, julia

I am trying to build a small GUI using Julia. In particular, I want to have drag&drop functionality. So far I have been playing around with the `Gtk.jl` package, just because it seems to be the more mature one.

I have read the [documentation](http://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/index.html) but I have been unable of finding any reference to drag&drop functionality. Do you know if it is possible at all to build drag&drpo functionality with `Gtk.jl`? If yes, how do you do it? If not, what other package can you suggest for building a GUI with drag&drop in Julia?